# C++ Copy and modify argv[]

Tags: c++

How could I copy argv vector into a new one in order to modify it and then pass new arguments to a function? Sorry if it's a basic stuff, I am not a C++ programmer.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    parseCommandLine(argc, argv);
```

and would like to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Here copy argv[] to argv2[] and modify argv2[0]

    parseCommandLine(argc, argv2);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Performed any research?

Comment: Since you appear to be dealing with a C++ program, now is a good time to become a C++ programmer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list good luck!

Comment: Do you need to modify the arguments themselves, or just their ordering? It's unclear what you need to change here.

Comment: What do you mean with **modify**?

Comment: @Nichar: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modify

Comment: I mean that, from argv content fill argv2 and then modify an specific position as argv2[0]

Comment: Sorry but I think that is not a question to be downvoted. I am a programmer but not a C one... Well, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to copy argv:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char** argv2 = new char*[argc];

    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        argv2[i] = new char[strlen(argv[i])+1];
        strcpy(argv2[i],argv[i]);
    }

    std::cout << argv2[0] << std::endl;

    //do what you want with argv2

    for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        delete [] argv2[i];
    }

    delete [] argv2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How to transform argv more c++ style. See [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3e629d7a0a3c6b6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args(argc);

    std::transform( argv, argv+argc, args.begin(),
        [&]( char*arg ){ return std::string(arg); } );

    std::cout << args[0];
}
```